# Regex : Match Character if follow by string ccontainning himself

Tags: regex, pandas

I try to match the first character '.' in '-2.232.232'.
I am close to it by this regex

```
^[^\.]*(\.)(?=.*\.)
```

but it match '-2.' insted of '.'.

Thank you very much

Comment: Just use `\.(?=[^.]*\.)` with a method that only matches once. What is the programming language?

Comment: I import data where sometimes is in american notation (2,323.43) and sometimes in european notation (2323.43). Because of pandas the string  ',' is transformed to '.'. So here is my question. I am using Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with the `n` argument set to `1`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':['-2.232.232']})
df['Data'].str.replace(r"\.(?=[^.]*\.)", "", n=1)
# => 0    -2232.232
```

Here,

- `\.(?=[^.]*\.)` - matches a dot that is followed with any zero or more chars other than a dot and then a dot char
- `n=1` - sets the number of replacements. `n=1` means *only one replacement*.

Alternatively, you may use

```py
>>> df['Data'].str.replace(r"^([^.]*)\.(?=[^.]*\.)", r"\1", n=1)
0    -2232.232
```

Here, `^([^.]*)` matches and captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `.` from the start of the string, and the `\1` refers to that value from the replacement pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't understand the n=1. Imagine that we have multi character match. How did he decided the one to replace? I erase n=1 in your example and it worked fine aswell;

Comment: @Kareivis It is because there are only two dots in the input string. See [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/3yN850/1) with three dots.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your time.